# Display contents of bib-file in tree-structure in TeXnicCenter 2.02 stable when using biblatex

Tags: biblatex

Unfortunately, the contents of the bib-file are only displayed if the command `\bibliography` is present in the preamble. However, when using biblatex the path to the bib-file is given by `\addbibresource`. Although a [ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/user-reports/1214/) with a request addressing this issue was posted on the sourceforge page of Texniccenter in 2011 and added to the feature list in 2012 the problem is still present in  the last release of TeXnicCenter (2.02 stable) which was released in September 2013.

If found a hack to solve this issue in a German forum [here](https://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?73729-Anzeige-von-Literatur-im-Texniccenter-bei-Verwendung-des-biblatex-Package-mit-biber) posted by Ulrike Fischer. I will post an example as an answer to my own question which I also posted on the sourceforge page. I hope it will help other users. Better solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your bibliography is a local BibTeX formatted database i.e. a `.bib` on the local file system, then

```
\bibliography{references}
```

will work fine with Biblatex.

Biblatex considers this 'deprecated', even though it is a core LaTeX command and not Biblatex's to deprecate or not.

However, it still works just fine. Indeed, if you need to load a whole series of bibliographies, it's the only sane option, as Biblatex's `\addbibresource` can only handle one at a time.

Only if your bibliography database is not BibTeX format or non-local *must* you use `\addbibresource`.

Comment: I think that it is not entirely unreasonable or out of line for `biblatex` to deprecate `\bibliography`. After all the original `\bibliography` works entirely different from `biblatex`'s implementation and so it really isn't a core command any more. Of course PL could have decided not to support `\bibliography` at all, but allowing the old command while pushing for use of the new, more versatile `\addbibresource` seems OK to me.

Comment: Compare the situation to the core command `\bibliographystyle` which is not usable at all with `biblatex` (it is redefined to produce an error). Is that also unacceptable?

Comment: @moewe Part of my objection is that `\bibliography` is much more convenient to use. There's a good substitute for `\bibliographystyle`. There's no good substitute for `\bibliography`. (And no, 20 lines of code rather than 1 does not make a good substitute.)

Comment: @moewe Also, I don't think that refusing to support a command is the same as declaring it 'deprecated'. `\bibliographystyle` is not deprecated. It just isn't compatible with Biblatex. That's fine. But saying it is 'deprecated' isn't, because that's not up to Biblatex. I would find it much less objectionable (though also much less convenient) if Biblatex just said **it** doesn't support `\bibliography` and threw an error to that effect. But it is not 'deprecated' anymore than `thebibliography` is 'deprecated' by BibTeX.

Comment: Mhhh, the substitute for `\bibliography{<file>}` is just `\addbibresource{<file>.bib}` only six characters longer (I will admit that it does not allow a list of files, so that would be more complicated). I also think that the way `biblatex` redefines `\bibliography` (it doesn't print the bibliography any more, it must be used in the preamble, the implementation is completely different) already makes it `biblatex`'s and not the core's. And what is `biblatex`'s it can deprecate.

Comment: @moewe If I had a single bibliography, six characters would hardly matter. But 20 lines of code rather than 1 is a different kettle of tofu.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the bib-file 'references.bib' is placed in your main latex folder. Insert the following commands in the preamble:

```
\bibliography{references} % Just for texniccenter, will be 'disabled' in the next line
\def\bibliography#1{} % Redefine \bibliography to do nothing
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

Comment: Completely unnecessary: just delete lines 2 and 3.

Comment: Should you not first disable `\bibliography` and then use it and not the other way round? `\renewcommand*{\bibliography}[1]{}\bibliography{references}\addbibresource{references.bib}`. Plus as cfr says for most intents and purposes `\bibliography{references}` alone is enough. For cases where `\addbibresource` is required I doubt that TeXnicCenter would be able to pick up the file or make sense of it anyway.